# c++ string_literals s postfix cant print string concatenated this way

Tags: c++, string, unicode, character-encoding, string-literals

I'm trying to learn about string literals and the likes and I've been playing around with it. Currently facing the problem of being unable to wcout a string that was the concatenation of two string literals appended with the "string"s method.

`std::string concat = "Hello, "s + "World!";`

It doesn't have any compiler errors if I cast to a string or make a call to a string constructor to concatenate them.

I'm also having trouble getting wcout to actually output unicode characters. I use cout elsewhere in the code.

`constexpr wchar_t* surname = L"shirts \u0444 \u1300";`

outputs shirts but no unicode characters when I `wcout << surname;`  If I just cout surname I get hex.

---

Edit:  thanks to comments I have understood the problem of wcout. I didn't realize it would only work with wstring and I was avoiding ordinary cout due to having read something about not mixing the two that I have yet to fully understand.

I still can't get the symbols to print out in wchar_t* which just outputs ordinary ascii characters.

Thanks for the swift replies thus far!

---

wcout works for normal chars marked with u8 but nothing else it seems. Several wcout statements just aren't outputting anything after the shirt fail, I moved them before it and they were printed out but they were hex rather than characters as expected. So far only normal char* have worked. This is such a headache...

Comment: `wcout` is for wide character strings, `std::wstring`s, only.

Comment: *"I'm also having trouble getting wcout to actually output unicode characters."*: Does your shell support unicode ?

Comment: I'm on windows 10 using visual studio 15  2017

Comment: You can't output UTF-8 strings with `std::wcout`. You must use `std::wstring` or `wchar_t*` only.  `std::cout` *MAY* support UTF-8, but it depends on the console's capabilities, font, etc. You really should stick with `std:wstring` for Unicode output.

Comment: Really? That's confusing. I'll try it out. I thought the point of wchar_t is that it is the minimum size to represent any character on the system except windows where its 16 bits, and that the char16_t and char32_t were to represent utf-16 and utf-32? But if you cant cout or wcout I'm beginning to wonder if they are even worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

As for no Unicode console output, you may have to set the locale, that is:

```
std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
constexpr wchar_t* surname = L"shirts \u0444 \u1300";
wcout << surname;
```

Comment: I set the locale and it still doesn't work. IT's not just outputting symbols it is preventing the next couple of wcout statements from working too...